# What is wrong in my question? Need advice

Tags: discussion

Today [I asked for help with a problem I am encountering with ngrx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60579580/lost-feature-state-in-ngrx-form), since I am not expert with this library, and I really need help.

I have been a user of Stack Overflow for a few years and I try to stick to the rules.
Can anyone help me understand what's wrong with my request, so that I can obtain the help I need?

Comment: I'd assume that SO contributors weren't all that happy that you couldn't narrow it down to a minimum repro with less than 108 errors.

Comment: Not familiar with ngrx, but it's definitely not a minimal repro. Is it? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example : Step 1 is **Restarting from scratch**. *Create a new program, adding in only what is needed to see the problem. Use simple, descriptive names for functions and variables – don’t copy the names you’re using in your existing code.*. I don't think your question has any evidence of attempting to follow step1. Then there are other steps..

Comment: @TheMaster I have included all the details I have, and removed all the noise, leaving only the necessary code, I am sorry, but ok

Comment: There is a lot of code and screenshots. If seasoned devs in that tool-stack find it totally understandable that the debugger is stopped in a method that is in none of your .ts files then your question is fine. I would put a bit more effort in to make clear which execution path is followed between all those .ts files and specially which bits *work* so you get a focus on what doesn't work and when it stops working.  If this doesn't make sense, then please ignore as I'm not familiar with any of the stuff that question is about.

Comment: @rene the debugger is stuck in a method included in the question, look better, is it verbose? Yes it is verbose, ngrx is well known for this, I am sorry. Ok, all the best and have a nice day, I am sure that with a bounty will be better

Comment: It's still not restarting from scratch. Is it? Bottom line, you didn't restart/ you didn't even start step 1 of debugging.  The mcve is not just for question's quality sake.  It's for your sake too. It's kind of the absolute 101's of debugging. Debugging is a art that comes by practice. Creating a new program  or restarting might a burden at first. But it helps a lot and is the first thing expected from  questions asking for debugging help. To put in other words, experts will have to rewrite your program from scratch, if you don't. You're essentially making them do your work.Thus the downvote